# Remove whitespace in <td> but only outside of <span> elements

Tags: php, html, css, whitespace

I want to remove whitespaces inside a `<td>` element. 
Inside this element I have several `<span>` elements and between them are unnecessary whitespaces. Is there a way to remove them without removing the whitespaces inside the `<span>` element?

I've no possibility to remove them in the code and I've to deal with them by using css or to change the PHP output.

I had the following idea but it removes (of course) all whitespaces:

```
echo str_replace(' ', '', $total['value']);
```

I also tried a CSS approach:

```
white-space: pre-line
```

But this adds a line bevore every space...

Are there any other ideas?

**EDIT:**
This is what I have:

```
<td class="totals totals_amount_order_total">
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;636,17</span>
                                <br class="wgm-break">
                                <span class="wgm-tax includes_tax">EnthÃ¤lt<span class="amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;101,57</span></span> MwSt. (19%)</span>
                          </td>
```

I now want to remove all whitespaces between the tags (but not in the text inside the tags):

```
<td class="totals totals_amount_order_total"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;636,17</span><br class="wgm-break"><span class="wgm-tax includes_tax">EnthÃ¤lt<span class="amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;101,57</span</span> MwSt. (19%)</span></td>
```

EDIT 2: 
I've tried to replace all `<span>` tags with a whitespace before them. I tried to do this with `preg_replace` but I'm not sure how to set a wildcard for the different classes inside the span

Comment: Is this to simply prettify your final output?

Comment: Post a sample input, desired output, what output you get with your trials, then we can help.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new = preg_replace('/>\s*</','><',$orig);
```

Works for me!  From your sample input and output, I noticed that you only remove whitespace between tags.

Complete code from my test:

```
    $orig="<td class=\"totals totals_amount_order_total\">
                            <span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">€</span>&nbsp;636,17</span>
                            <br class=\"wgm-break\">
                            <span class=\"wgm-tax includes_tax\">EnthÃ¤lt<span class=\"amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">€</span>&nbsp;101,57</span></span> MwSt. (19%)</span>
                      </td>";

    $new = preg_replace('/>\s*</','><',$orig);
    print($new);
```

I get this (view source):

```
 <td class="totals totals_amount_order_total"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;636,17</span><br class="wgm-break"><span class="wgm-tax includes_tax">EnthÃ¤lt<span class="amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>&nbsp;101,57</span></span> MwSt. (19%)</span></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea. But I tried it and it doesn't work. The whitespaces are still there.

Comment: Logs, errors, ...?  I just did it on my PHP, works fine.

Comment: sorry, there are no shown errors. It's replacing the data. I can see that because I added some stuff in the replacement. but the spaces are still there

Comment: it kinda works with the '<pre>' tags. but now I've a new line above the text

Comment: I edited my answer with my test code and output.  The <pre> is just an output thing for me, I remove them, same result.

Comment: @Cray Note that if you are using your browser to check this, your browser itself may be adding whitespace for readability. Hence the suggestion to output within`<pre>` tags (or check with some other form of raw output formatting)

Comment: as I said with '<pre>' it's working but it adds a new line before the text

Comment: You could ltrim the output.

Comment: I guess the problem is, that there are spans inside spans. so the whitespace in the second span is still there.

Comment: @Cray One of your updates says "I now want to remove all whitespaces between the tags (but not in the text inside the tags)" According to that request, "whitespace in the second span" _should_ remain, since it is "between the tags". Perhaps you need to come up with a more precise definition of what you want.

Comment: What I find weird is that your sample output matches my output, yet it`s not what you want.   Signing out.

Comment: I found a solution, I'm using your code and need to remove the '<br class="wgm-break">'. I tried to do so with 'preg_replace('/<br class=\"wgm-break\">', '', $total['value']);' but it doesn't work. Is there an error in the preg_replace?